# Move/Rotate/Scale selected Object by Arrow Hotkeys?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, customization, navigation

I feel a bit stupid to ask, but is it possible to move/rotate/scale my object by arrow hotkeys (left=Move, Down=Rotate, right=scale, up=gizmo). This i believe would really speed up my workflow.

It will be super helpful and I will take any solution from experts or pros on the matter, Thx as always, Stewart

Comment: You can do it, just go to Edit > Preferences > Keymap.. serch for the move, rote and scale, then change it.

Comment: thx so much... i also just find it by right-click the icon and set hotkey faster :)